# Radgrid pager disappear if selected items per page exceed items in grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a pager in a Radgrid with the following properties:

```
AllowPaging="True" AlwaysVisible="true"
```

The problem: If I have 40 items in the grid and I select 50 in the pager, the pager disappear and therefore the user cannot change it back to 10 or 20 anymore.
Is there a way to set the pager to stay visible even if the pager selected items per page exceed the quantity of items in the grid?

Comment: You said the `AlwaysVisible` property is set to "True". Is it the `MasterTableView-PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible` property or the RadGrid's one? Try setting every single one of them.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders, thanks a lot. Your suggestion solved my problem. Please post it as answer so I can reward your suggestion properly. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, posted the answer down bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting every single `AlwaysVisible` property you can find to `True`, including the RadGrid's and the MasterTableView (MasterTableView-PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible).

Comment: Wow this saved my few remaining strands of hair on a custom export to PDF, where despite my attempts to hide the pager on the RadGrid it was always shown in the PDF. Turns out it was the MasterTableView's pager.